# Why does jQuery.ready run when the page isnt ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so often i put jquery document ready functions at the bottom of my html, just to have it run before all the elements of the page are loaded. i'm tired of my functions not working because resources arent finished loading on the page, jquery.ready keeps saying the elements are done loading when they arent! who wants to set a 300ms timeout just so that their functions wait a little after jquery.ready?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code? On what elements does this actually happen?

Comment: I’m gonna remove all the tags but jquery as this seems to be a  question explicitly about a jquery function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `.ready()` to perform actions when the DOM is ready for scripting.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

Use `.load()` to perform actions when the "page" (resources including files and images) is loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
});
```

Answer (score 6):

jQuery.ready fires when DOM elements are ready, not when scripts/images/etc finish loading.

Description from the docs on .ready():

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 3):

As simshaun said, jQuery.ready fires when the DOM is ready - not when things like images are ready. If you want to wait for images to be loaded, you have to use the following code:

```
$(window).load(
    function() {
        // do stuff here
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

$.ready runs when DOM is loaded not when the page is fully loaded (images etc...)

Perhaps you're looking for

$(window).load(function() {
  // stuff
});

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery API documentation:

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts.

So, use the load event if you need *everything* to be finished loading but if you only need the DOM to be ready, use the ready event.

Answer (score 0):

`.ready()` function runs when the DOM is ready not the binary data is loaded. to ensure that the binary data is loaded you can use `.load()` function